# Ternary Merkle Tree - concatenation and Merkle Proof?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, merkle-tree

Unlike binary Merkle trees, ternary have 3 leaf nodes. I wanted to understand how do we eventually get to the Root Merkle node -- is it by concatenating in the pair of 3 (considering 3 leaves in every set) or do we still make pairs (of 2)?

I would appreciate if someone would explain this. Thanks!

Comment: Which ternary Merkle tree? What design are you talking about? Bitcoin only uses binary Merkle trees to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: That's right! Bitcoin only uses binary merkle trees, however, in general there is a concept of ternary merkle trees as well and I wanted to understand if it works similarly by hashing then grouping individual nodes. If so, does it group and hash the hashes of all three child nodes together?